# Is my Italian residency permit valid after the visa in my passport expires?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, italy, italian-residents, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am currently in Italy and I have a student's visa that is valid until the beginning of October and I received my permesso di soggiorno that is valid until the end of the year. Can I stay here after my visa expires or I have to return to my country before?

Answer (score 3):

[This resource](http://campagneinlotta.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/vademecumENG.pdf) states that a person can stay in Italy until the expiration date of their permesso di soggiorno. This is one of the best documents I found in English but can't verify the credibility

Answer (score 2):

> Does permesso di soggiorno override the visa?

**Yes it does**, meaning your permission to stay expires when the permesso does.

While the visa is valid, you can use either that or the permesso to enter Italy, but after the visa expired, you must use the permesso.

If you want to stay for longer, you Need to apply for an Extension of the permesso

Comment: Also it gives me the right to travel around in Europe right?

Comment: @ÖnderErgüven In the Schengen Area and to Croatia, Romania and Bulgaria. Also, your Turkish passport alone lets you visit the CEFTA states, Belarus and Ukraine

Comment: Assertion without evidence

Comment: @Berwyn Common sense - if the visa expiry date constituted the day by which you must leave, the permesso would hardly have a later expiry date

Comment: It's not about common sense, it's about justification via information from official links. How is the OP supposed to believe your claim?

Comment: @Berwyn OK, so let's assume I'm wrong, and OP must leave the country before the visa expires. Why would the permesso then state they can stay for even longer if that's not the case?

Comment: @Crazydre my visa expires on 10 October 2017 but my permesso is valid until 25 December 2017

Comment: @ÖnderErgüven Exactly, so you can stay until 25 December (or longer if you extend the permesso), that's exactly what I mean. The visa expiry date was only important **before** you got the permesso